# Layout visibility changing is possible while i am in another layout?

Tags: android

Here I create four **xml** files `main.xml`,`test1.xml`,`test2.xml`,`test3.xml`.

They are accessed in `spinner` but I received an exception.
I am giving **logcat** also.

Please help me.

```
String[] lan = { "test1", "test2", "test3" };

Spinner spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lan);

spn.setAdapter(adapter);

spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
        if (pos == 0) {
            findViewById(R.layout.test1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (pos == 1) {
            findViewById(R.layout.test2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (pos == 2) {
            findViewById(R.layout.test3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
```

Logcat:

```
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at com.venky.innverlayoutchangevisibility.MainActivity$1.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:30)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
07-11 18:09:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try `MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.layout.test1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: I am try but no use.Same exception is rising

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive you can't do this. According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)

> Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).

This is used to find the `View` inside the currently inflated `layout` which I understand these to be separate files. You will need to use an [`inflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html). Or in this situation call `setContentView()` if you don't need to use any of the current `Views` after an item is selected

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
            long id) {
        int layout;   // create int for layout to inflate
        if (pos == 0) {
            layout = R.layout.test1;   // assign int according to the layout needed
        } else if (pos == 1) {
            layout = R.layout.test2;
        } else if (pos == 2) {
           layout = R.layout.test3;
        }
        setContentView(layout);      // inflate the layout
    }
```

**Note** doing this will set your `View`s in the `layout` you `inflate` to their defaults and `View`s from the original `layout` inflated in `onCreate()` won't exist. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for or not. If not, let me know.

**Edit**

Now that I know these `layouts` are `include`ed in your main `layout`, you don't want to use

```
    findViewById(R.layout.test3)
```

When you use the `<include>` tag to insert them in your main `layout` give them an `id` and use that `id` in

```
     findViewById(R.id.test3)
```

Comment: Oh no. I want not this. I have 4 xml files. In Activity i have spinner while select spinner that related xml file visibility is changed. In Main xml i use this code  <include layout="@layout/test1" />

        <include layout="@layout/test2" />

        <include layout="@layout/test3" /> .Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereYou cannot use components from a different layout like. What you need to do is define a `LayoutInflator` and work from that. `R.id.yourComponent` can only access components defined (mostly) in the onCreate method like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

To do what you need, create an inflator for each one of your Layouts (NOTE: To make this work, give an ID to each one of the main LinearLayouts in your test1.xml, test2.xml, test3.xml and access that, instead of the file itself):

```
String[] lan = { "test1", "test2", "test3" };

Spinner spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lan);

//Duplicate this code for every .xml layout inside your onItemSelected
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View firstView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, null); //inflates test1.xml
LinearLayout test1Layout = (LinearLayout) firstView.findViewById(R.id.idOfTheLayout); //This finds a component inside your test1.xml file. As mentioned, give the highest Layout which holds all your components an ID.
test1Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


spn.setAdapter(adapter);

spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
            long id) {
        if (pos == 0) {
            findViewById(R.layout.test1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (pos == 1) {
            findViewById(R.layout.test2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (pos == 2) {
            findViewById(R.layout.test3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```